# Using Excel VBA, to enter a formula in an equation

Tags: vba, formula, bloomberg

Using Excel, Cell of A1 is a formula which is =B1/BDP(C1&" CORP","DS036")
Which BDP(DS036) is a function from Bloomberg.

However, there are bunch of rows that why I want to use Excel VBA to run the data automatically. The ways I’ve tried were like the code below. But, it does not work. Could you tell me how to fix it? Appreciate.

```
           b = Worksheets("ABC").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           Worksheets("ABC").Cells(b + 1, 1).Formula = "=" & Worksheets("ABC").Cells(b + 1,2) & "/" & "BDP(" & Worksheets("ABC").Cells(b + 1, 3) &"" CORP"" ,""DS036"")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/BDP(RC[2]&"" CORP"",""DS036"")"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Learns from it